# net core api controller method runs differently on release configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, configuration, controller

I have a standard Net core Api solution. My Business layer service, connects to DB , maps the `LogModel` with DTO and returns it to controller to return to the client.

[image: solution]

I can edit `LogModelDTO` however I like and it works perfectly in Debug configuration, but when I publish my code, or just choose Release configuration, it seems my application ignores my changes to DTO model.

Here I commented out some properties:
[image: DTO class]

Postman results:
[image]

In debug configuration it returns only Id property, which is expected.

How can I fix this?

edit: I cleaned my solution and Release configuration started working, but when I publish my app, it still seems to ignore the changes I make...

Comment: Delete all the files in the release folder or clear all the files in publish folder and try again.

Answer (score 1):

When publishing, do you have the setting to overwrite files activated?

Comment: This and like I said Clean solution solved my problem. Thank you